# Google Maps zoom number and min/max scale(Openlayers)

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, openlayers

How to set Google maps' zoom number accordingn to min/max scale of a wms layer? If min scale is 1/50000 and max scale is 1/5000 (units: m), which zoom number is resonable? I tried to set min zoom number to 10, it worked fine, but I got problem with max zoom number.I tried 20 and 22, but Google Streets and Google Physical gave no responce when zoomed in (only the wms layer zoomed, see the screenshot). 
[image]

Any tips how to set zoom number?

Comment: Open layers 2 or 3?

Comment: @JohnBarça It's 3.